# More efficient way of windows/level adjustment of image? C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm writing this program for my image processing course and I need to create a window of size 30 (I'm assuming 30 pixels since my instructor didn't specify) where I perform a linear gray scale transformation of all the pixels that are within the window frame. I've written the following code:

```
// create a window 30 image to modify
 Mat window30(relax.size(), relax.type());
 // traverse through the whole image with our 5x6 window and linearly transform the pixel values in the image
 for (int i = 0; i < window30.rows; i=i+5)
 {
      for (int j = 0; j < window30.cols; j=j+6)
      {
           for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
           {
                for (int m = 0; m < 6; m++)
                {
                     // if pixel value is below 50 set that value to 0
                     if (window30.at<uchar>(i+n,j+m) < 50)
                     {
                          window30.at<uchar>(i + n, j + m) = 0;
                     }
                     // if between 50 and 169 transform it to the value multiplied by 1.08875
                     else if (window30.at<uchar>(i + n, j + m) >= 50 and window30.at<int>(i + n, j + m) < 170)
                     {
                          window30.at<uchar>(i + n, j + m) = 1.08875 * window30.at<int>(i + n, j + m);
                     }
                     // else just set value to 255
                     else
                     {
                          window30.at<uchar>(i + n, j + m) = 255;
                     }
                }
           }
      }
 }
 imshow("window30", window30);
 waitKey(0);
```

This is my first time every working with computer vision using OpenCV and with C++. I know my code is trash but I've been stuck on this problem the whole day and know there's got to be a way to do this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and the most recent version of OpenCV.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: why are you doing it like this, in blocks? that's potentially slower than doing it the simple way. and what language is this where you have an `and` operator? C++ doesn't have those unless you use a preprocessor define. if you want the most efficient method, work with whole Mats and masks. `Mat mask1 = (window30 < 50), mask2 = (window30 >=170); ...some more stuff here... window30.setTo(0, mask1); window30.setTo(255, mask2);`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz `C++` does actually have the `and` and `or` operators, they are just, culturally, not used much. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: You can also speed-up your `cv::Mat` accesses using the `Mat` iterator: [cv::MatIterator_](https://riptutorial.com/opencv/example/23884/alternative-pixel-access-with-matiterator) very useful if you are performing multiple operations on contiguous pixels.